# Maven exec with ProcessBuilder stops processing

Tags: java, windows, maven, cmd, processbuilder

I am running my code as;

```
mvn exec:java@xxxxxxxxxxxx -Dexec.args="hello"
```

I don't know why but somehow it stops processing. It is getting stuck after 10 or 20 seconds. But this is happening with the ProcessBuilder;

Here is how I run it:

```
public static long runCommandLine(String commandLineArgs){
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", commandLineArgs);
            Process process = pb.start();
            if(!commandLineArgs.contains("runner")) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                while ((reader.readLine()) != null) { /*haha*/}
                process.waitFor();
            }
            return process.pid();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I send the .bat file's path to the method as an argument (String commandLineArgs);

.bat file contains lines:

```
cd C:/xxxx/%username%/xxx
mvn exec:java@xxxxxxxxxxxx -Dexec.args="hello"
```

If I run the .bat file manually, everything is okay. But with the ProcessBuilder it will get stuck after a while.

pom.xml configutarion:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xxxxxxxx</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>xxxxxxxxxxx</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: `ProcessBuilder.redirectError` and `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput` should be used and afterwards you can read from it...

Comment: @khmarbaise okay, I added them and they are working right now. But I really don't understand why logging solved my problem ? I don't want to use it. Because I am already using apache loggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as khmarbaise mentioned "ProcessBuilder.redirectError and ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput should be used and afterwards you can read from it...", the solution is adding redirects.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of a process apparently pausing some time after ProcessBuilder.start() is often related to your application not consuming the stdout and stderr streams as they are generated. So if not calling redirectError/redirectOutput(File) as suggested, just set up a Runnable/Thread to consume both of getInputStream / getErrorStream.